# Minimum Path Sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, depth-first-search

I'm working on an algorithm problem where you have to find the minimum path sum of a grid where you can move up, down, left, or right, and you cannot repeat a square. I wrote a recursive solution to solve it (I know DP would be better), but it outputs 0 as the answer every time, but finds the minimum sum to be 215 (should be 87). How would I fix the code to solve it?

Also, how could I use DP to implement this?

Here is my code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int rows;
int cols;
/*
 * assumes max grid size is 1000x1000
 * could go larger if necessary, but memory use will increase
 */
int grid[1000][1000]; 
bool isMarked[1000][1000];

int calc(int row, int col, int sum) {
    if (isMarked[row][col])
        return INT_MAX - sum;
    isMarked[row][col] = true;
    sum += grid[row][col];
    if (row == rows-1 && col == cols-1)
        return sum;

    int ans[4];
    if (row-1 >= 0) 
        ans[0] = calc(row-1, col, sum);
    if (row+1 < rows) 
        ans[1] = calc(row+1, col, sum);
    if (col+1 < cols)
        ans[2] = calc(row, col+1, sum);
    if (col-1 >= 0)
        ans[3] = calc(row, col-1, sum);
    isMarked[row][col] = false;
    return std::min(std::min(ans[0], ans[1]), std::min(ans[2], ans[3]));
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("sum.in");
    fin >> rows >> cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            fin >> grid[i][j];

    int ans = calc(0, 0, 0);

    std::ofstream fout("sum.out");
    fout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: I didn't use a debugger, but I did quite a bit of testing with print statements. It seems like most of the path ends are squares that were already marked, which makes sense. All the paths that do make it to the end seem to be returning 215, when the correct answer should be 87.

Comment: Use the debugger.

Comment: You're taking the `min` of 4 things (`a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]`), whether or not those values are set.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use your observation to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
int calc(int row, int col, int sum) {
    if (isMarked[row][col])
        return INT32_MAX;
    if (row == rows-1 && col == cols-1)
        return sum+grid[row][col];

    isMarked[row][col] = true;
    int ans[4] = {INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX};
    if (row-1 >= 0)
        ans[0] = calc(row-1, col, sum+grid[row][col]);
    if (row+1 < rows)
        ans[1] = calc(row+1, col, sum+grid[row][col]);
    if (col+1 < cols)
        ans[2] = calc(row, col+1, sum+grid[row][col]);
    if (col-1 >= 0)
        ans[3] = calc(row, col-1, sum+grid[row][col]);
    isMarked[row][col] = false;

    return std::min(std::min(ans[0], ans[1]), std::min(ans[2], ans[3]));
}
```